# Mongodb not using single field index in aggregation

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with an indexed field `country` and I am trying to couunt how many documents exist per country as follows:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {"$group" : {_id:"$,country", count:{$sum:1}}}
])
```

Which gives the intended result however, I notice it's not using the created index and scanning all documents. is this normal by mongo if so how can I make it use the index.

```
"executionStats" : {
                    "executionSuccess" : true,
                    "nReturned" : 6616784,
                    "executionTimeMillis" : 22783,
                    "totalKeysExamined" : 0,
                    "totalDocsExamined" : 6616784,
```

Answer (score 0):

The aggregation query is not using the index because it is more efficient not to.

An index lists the documents with the indexed fields in sorted order, while the storage engine stores the documents in pages, effectively grouped by insertion order.

This means that in the data file, the documents are unsorted.  When you query for a few specific countries, the index improves the performance because it only needs to load pages that contain a matching country value.  Since the index identifies the documents in order of index value, this also means that sorting by the indexed field is inherent, and no additional sort is required.

If you aren't going to sort, using the index will only improve performance if you are reading less than around 60-70% of the documents in the collection.

Above that threshold, performance is not improved because the query executor will wind up visiting nearly every page anyway, and because the documents will be retrieved in order of the index, i.e. sorted by by country, it will occasionally have to revisit previsously visited pages, some multiple times.

If the collection is sufficiently, or load on the server sufficiently high, that the entire collection cannot be maintained in the cache all at once, this revisiting of previously seen pages can result in the same page being read from disk and evicted from cache multiple times.

In the case of this aggregation, the query planner can see that you are going to read every document in the collection, and there is no sorting.  In this situation it is most efficient to read the documents in the order that they appear in the data file, so not index is used.

For the case of counting occurrences of individual values, when none of the documents contain an array for that value, the query executor can use a COUNT_SCAN phase.  This means it can count the occurrences directly from the index without reading any documents.

You might test running a `distinct` query on the country field (which should be able to use the index), and then submit a separate `count` command for each value.  While this would require quite a few more round trips on the network, it would also read about 6 million fewer documents from the disk.  I would be quite curious how the performance would compare.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue recently and it appear that it is a bug in mongoDB , the workaraund is simply to advice(hint) the query planner to use the index and it show the expected better performance:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
 [
  {
   "$group" : { 
             _id:"$country", count:{$sum:1}
            }
   }
 ],
 {
   hint:"country_1"
 }
)
```

Tested in 4.0.16 , 4.2.12 and 4.4.14